# C# and Twilio - Voicemail POST not working

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-api

I'm following the example here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/twiml/greet-caller-by-name

Although I've set it up slightly differently.  Rather than code it directly in the cshtml I have a controller action reading from my database to retrieve the name of the person with the mobile number passed in.  Anyway....

When I phone my Twilio number, I've set it up (the automated voicemail) to POST to a webpage I've specified (https://www.XXX.co.uk/Twilio/Voicemail) and say "Hi [user name]" as opposed to "Hi there" (if it can't find a user). However it currently doesn't find the user because the parameter ("FROM") doesn't get POSTed successfully.

If I manually post using Fiddler and specify:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

in the request, it works. If I take this out, it doesn't work (so i assume Twilio doesn't include this when POSTing?). My action signature looks like this:

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Voicemail(FormCollection collection)
{

And I'm tracing 'collection'.

Any advice?

Thanks.

***UPDATE***

I've also tried with:
    public ActionResult Voicemail(VoiceRequest request)
    {
        string mobileNumber = request.From;

but I still don't get the POSTed values.

Comment: Are you sure you've configured the webhook to do a POST and not a GET?

Comment: Yes, definately set to POST.  I've also tried using VoiceRequest instead of FormCollection but still the same.  (I've tried editing my original post and adding the code)

Comment: One thing I DON'T do (mentioned here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp/creating-aspnet-mvc-webhook-project) is inherit TwilioController in my class ( : TwilioController).  Not sure if that would make any difference tbh, and I'm away from my dev machine at the moment.

Comment: I need to retest it this evening - i think one of my attempts worked (according to my logs), and the reason i didn't get the correct message response was because the POST mobile number is (+4477xxxx) and I store it in myb database as (077xxxx) so they didn't match up....

Comment: That is a very real possibility. All the numbers come in with their country codes.

Comment: Thanks Marcos.  Just to confirm, FormCollection did NOT work.  VoiceRequest DID work.  And i then needed to check the number properly due to the request prepending +44.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Answered above in comments:

> One thing I DON'T do (mentioned here:
>   https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp/creating-aspnet-mvc-webhook-project)
>   is inherit TwilioController in my class `: TwilioController`. Not sure
>   if that would make any difference tbh, and I'm away from my dev
>   machine at the moment.
>
> I need to retest it this evening - i think one of my attempts worked
>   (according to my logs), and the reason i didn't get the correct
>   message response was because the POST mobile number is (+4477xxxx) and
>   I store it in myb database as (077xxxx) so they didn't match up
>
> Just to confirm, `FormCollection` did NOT work. `VoiceRequest` DID work.
>   And i then needed to check the number properly due to the request
>   prepending +44 country code.